# Using read.csv, empty fields have NA added to data.frame

Tags: r

I am using read.csv to import a file that contains some columns with empty cells. I need these cells to remain empty and not contain any values.

However, an `NA` is getting added everytime I import. I have tried variations of `na.strings` (like `na.strings="NULL"` or `na.strings=""`) to no avail.

Is there a simple way to force the observations to remain empty?

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Are they otherwise numeric columns? In which case 'empty' doesn't have any meaning, and NA is what you use when you have missing value. Why don't you want them to be NA? What are you planning to do with them afterwards?

Comment: The other columns are a mix of character and numeric. In this case, I am exporting the data to an ecommerce site and whatever content is in the fields will often get displayed on the screen. For some of the fields there are rules that the values cannot all be the same and that system does not understand what NA means.

Comment: Then maybe you wan't no `NA` in export? Should be simpler.

Comment: @Marek you might be right. After removing the NA so the fields are NULL I found out I need to have them be unquoted. I added a question for that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826917/how-to-remove-double-quotes-around-null-values-in-write-csv

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After the import, try this:

```
x[is.na(x)] <- c("") ## Refills NA with blank character.
```

This converts the column to character but if you already have mixed strings I imagine it already is.